# Question about subsequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let's say I have a sequence $\{p_n\}$, whose range is the set $E$.  Let's say $E$ contains a sequence $\{s_n\}$.  Is $\{s_n\}$ necessarily a subsequence of $\{p_n\}$?

The definition of subsequences I must abide by is as follows:
For any sequence $\{p_n\}$ in a metric space $X$,
let $\{n_k\}$ be a sequence of natural numbers, with $n_1 < n_2 < \ldots < n_k$.
Then the sequence given by $\{p_{n_k}\}$ is a *subsequence* of $\{p_n\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the sequence $a_n = n$ and $b_n=1$.

In our case $E=\mathbb N$, and clearly $\{b_n\}\subseteq E$, but every subsequence of $a_n$ must have more than two distinct elements.

Comment: Can the downvoter explain?

Answer (score 2):

No certainly not. The moment you consider the range set, you lose the order on the terms of the sequence. Examples are easy to come up with.

Let's consider the metric space $\mathbb R$ with the euclidean metric. Consider the sequence

$$a_n=\dfrac{1}{2^n}$$

Now the range set $E$ of $a_n$ is $E=\left\{\dfrac{1}{2^n}\mid n \in \Bbb N \cup\{0\} \right\}$. Now consider the subsequence that looks like this, $$\frac 1 2,1,\frac1 {2^3},\frac 1 {2^2},\frac 1 {2^5},\frac{1}{2^4}, \cdots$$

That is the sequence $b_n$ is defined as, $$b_n=\begin{cases}\dfrac{1}{2^{n+1}}, \mbox{When } n=2k ~~\mbox{for some} k \in \Bbb N\cup \{0\}\\\dfrac{1}{2^{n-1}}\mbox{When } n=2k+1 ~~\mbox{for some} k \in \Bbb N\cup \{0\}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Would you mind providing please one or two such examples?

Comment: I have added an example, is that fine?

Comment: Your added statement is false. Think about $a_n=0$ for even $n$ and $a_n=n$ otherwise. It has a constant subsequence but the range is infinite.

Comment: Hmph, true. Sorry for that wrong version. One obvious direction is true, though. :/